# Lee Sin's ulti animation, counters and ways to cancel the animation

Tags: league-of-legends

Who are the champions who can counter lee sin's ulti with a dash, a blink or escape?

For instance, Yasuo's E can counter lee sin's ulti. However if someone cancels the animation with kick flash then Yasuo doesn't complete his ability, I think the same is true for Tristana. Can you give a list of champions who counter lee sin's ulti if you don't cancel the animation.

Is there any other way to cancel the animation without using the flash?  By activating hydra can you cancel the animation?

Edit:  by counter, I mean that the animation of the dash is shorter than lee sin's ultimate.

Comment: What do you mean by "counter" Lee's ultimate? Pretty sure once the Lee targets you and presses R there's no way to escape if the move starts its animation.

Comment: you can't dodge it , but you can move behind lee with Yasuo because the animation of Yasuo'ds E is shorter than the animation of lee 's ulti. Eventually, you gonna kick Yasuo under his tower and he is gonna escape. On the other hand Lisandra's escape is much slower than lee's ulti so you can interrupt it easily.

Comment: Essentially you can't cancel his dash, you have to counter him before his dash, when I played shaco, I would always anticipate his sonic wave, and I would throw my jack in the box, like all lee sins they will mash their sonic wave to dash upon hit, so they would dash to my jack in the box, get feared and I keep running.

Comment: if you cancel the animation the kick happens immediately, and you cancel his dash I think right?

Comment: @user12.5.5_19.9.14 I don't think that Flash cancels the animation, it just repositions Lee during the animation. The target still gets hit at the same time after casting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is most important is probably your timing. If you react to late your escape will just be canceled and you will not get to your tower.

Lee Sins ult cast time is approximately 0.25 seconds (from ). So it depends on how close he is. If he is really close then it is easier since you don't have to get far to get behind him. If he is at his max. ult range (375) then it is harder since you have to get further away

```
    Who are the champions who can counter lee sin's ulti with a dash, a blink or escape?

    Ahri (450 r range), Caitlyn (400 e range), Corki (600 w, 1800 with special delivery), 
    Ekko (325 e dash range, 425 e attack range), Fiora (400 q range), Fizz (550 q range), 
    Gnar (475 e range), Graves (425 e range), Kassadin (500 r range), 
    Katarina (375 e range), Kha'Zix (700 e range, 900 evolved e range), Kindred (340 q range),
    LeBlanc (600 w range), Lucian (425 e range), Malphite (1000 r range), 
    Nidalee (375 w range), Rek'Sai (could not find his e range), Renekton (450 e range), 
    Riven (260 q range, 325 e range), Shaco (400 q range), Shyvana (1000 r range), 
    Tristana (900 w range), Tryndamere (660 e range), Yasuo (475 range)

    somethimes:
    Jarvan IV can do it with his q (770 range), if his e is already casted 

    on friendly champions/wards/minions:
    Braum with w (650 range) on minions/champions
    Jax with q (700 range)
    Lee Sin with w (700 range)

    on enemy champions/minions:
    Ekko (after his e dash - 425 e attack range)
    Jax with q (700 range)
    Irelia with q (650 range)
    Diana with r (825 range)
    Pantheon with w (600 range)
    Talon with e (700 range)
    Warwick with r (700 range)
```

I was not able to find all cast times, but most dashes/blinks/jumps have a cast time of ~0.25 seconds.

> Is there any other way to cancel the animation without using the flash? By activating hydra can you cancel the animation?

I don't think it is possible to cancel his ult animation. Hydra doesn't cancel it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Tristana is able to counter it in a way since once the W has begun casting, there is no way to stop it from going off other than killing Tristana. Yes, it will not stop Lee Sin from kicking you, but at least you will get out of a sticky situation if your opponents don't react fast enough. You have to time it correctly though, since displacement abilities (like Lee Sin's ultimate) *will* interrupt your jump if you are already in the air.
Ezreal is possibly another counter, even though I'm not 100% sure about this, if he blinks at the right time, causing the direction of the kick to change.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong.